# Search from one document library only in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-library, search

I want to search content from one document library only. How can we do that in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Where should the user search in this specific document library? From withing a specific page? A subsite? In a site collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the default [result source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/02/01/how-query-rules-and-result-sources-can-be-used-to-customize-search-results.aspx) to search only the library's path.